# How to disable CSRF for Django live server testing?

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-unittest

How do you disable CSRF for [live server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) tests in Django when using Selenium?

Any page the browser tries to visit with Selenium throws a CSRF failure. I've tried modifying my settings to remove `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` from my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and setting `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to `self.live_server_url` but those had no effect.

Unfortunately, `enforce_csrf_checks` doesn't seem to be supported when using Selenium.

Comment: Do you mean when submitting forms? Or when simply visiting a page?

Comment: You can try to get the CSRF code and use it within your unittest. I'm doing that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017587/cant-test-password-change-in-django-unittest