# Can't test password change in Django unittest

Tags: django, python-unittest, django-unittest

I'm trying to write an integration test for a Django application to test if the password was changed from a rest API. However, after calling the password change API, testing for the new password doesn't work.

What I'm doing here is: I change the password to `johnjohn` through a rest call, then try to check if the password is actually changed

My unittest file

```
import json
import urllib
import urllib2

import requests
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.test import TestCase
from adaptors.redis_class import DjangoRedis


class PasswordChange(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_user(username='john', email='john@john.com', password='john')
        # class for redis access  
        r = DjangoRedis()
        r.set("email:john@john.com", '0' * 40, ex=3600)
        r.set('0' * 40, "email:john@john.com", ex=3600)
    def test_change_password(self):
        # Fake url I set through redis
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/' + '0' * 40 + '/'
        r = requests.get(url)
        csrf_token = r.content.split('csrf_token')[1].split('"')[2]
        payload = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token, 'payload': json.dumps({'password': 'johnjohn'})}
        headers = {'Cookie': 'csrftoken=' + csrf_token}
        data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        json_res = json.loads(response.read())

        # This doesn't fail
        self.assertEqual(json_res['password_changed'], True)
        u = User.objects.get(username='john')

        # This fails
        self.assertEqual(u.check_password('johnjohn'),True)
```

My view

```
import hashlib
import random

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

from adaptors.redis_class import DjangoRedis
from constants import PASSWORD_RESET
from tasks import send_email
from util.rest import get_payload
class ResetPage(View):
    def post(self, requests, reset_token):
        r = DjangoRedis()
        token = r.get(reset_token)
        if token is None:
            return JsonResponse({"token": False})
        payload = get_payload(requests.POST)
        try:
            email = token.split(':')[1].lower()
            u = User.objects.get(email=email)
            u.set_password(payload['password'])
            u.save()
            r.delete(reset_token)
            r.delete('email:' + email)
            return JsonResponse({'password_changed': True})
        except ValueError:
            return JsonResponse({"password_changed": False, 'error': "can't get your email from the database (E01)"})
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({"password_changed": False, 'error': "User doesn't exist (E02)"})

    def get(self, requests, reset_token):
        r = DjangoRedis()
        if not r.get(reset_token):
            raise Http404
        return render(requests, "login/reset.html", {'token': reset_token})
```

The unittest file is called `rest_pass_login_tests.py` in a `unittests` directory.

I run it by using the following command.

`./manage.py test unittests/ --pattern="rest_pass_login_tests.py"`

When I test normally through the browser, the password change works fine. However, when I try to check if the password was changed or not through a unittest, I get an invalid password.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using django test client instead of urllib?

Comment: I'm using selenium, and I changed the code to use urllib. However, you're right about django test client

Answer (score 1):

I was using dev server to run unittests. When I changed my password, I was actually posting to the dev server instead of the test one.

Here is my new unittest

```
import json

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import Client
from django.test import TestCase

from adaptors.redis_class import DjangoRedis


class PasswordChange(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_user(username='john', email='john@john.com', password='john')
        r = DjangoRedis()
        r.set("email:john@john.com", '0' * 40, ex=3600)
        r.set('0' * 40, "email:john@john.com", ex=3600)

    def test_change_password(self):
        c = Client()
        payload = {'payload': json.dumps({'password': 'johnjohn'})}

        url = '/reset/' + '0' * 40 + '/'
        res = c.post(url, payload)
        res = res.json()
        self.assertEqual(res['password_changed'], True)
        u = User.objects.get(username='john')
        self.assertEqual(u.check_password('johnjohn'), True)
```

If you're going to use `selenium` IDE, make sure you inherent from `StaticLiveServerTestCase` instead of unittest. Follow [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase). Also, don't forget to change this variable `self.base_url` to `self.live_server_url`

This inside my setUp method

`self.base_url = self.live_server_url`

Thanks to [fips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1434070/fips), [koterpillar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288201/koterpillar) for helping me on the IRC channel, and [aks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2549021/aks) for commenting under me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not making an http `post` as your view expects.

Here is how to make a post using urllib2: [Making a POST call instead of GET using urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348499/making-a-post-call-instead-of-get-using-urllib2)

But, since you already use `requests` module why not simply do:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/' + '0' * 40 + '/'
payload = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token, 'payload': json.dumps({'password': 'johnjohn'})}
headers = {'Cookie': 'csrftoken=' + csrf_token}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
json_res = json.loads(r.content)
```

And maybe try debugging/printing the value of `json_res` to check if there's anything else unexpected.

Also note, this is an integration test as you are testing through http, so your urls.py, views.py and even settings.py are being tested as part of it.

Comment: ```[04/May/2016 03:18:48] "GET /reset/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3058
[04/May/2016 03:18:48] "POST /reset/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26
``` No, I'm doing a correct post. However, I will test your code

Comment: ```{u'password_changed': True}```. I have a CBV, and two methods, one for get, and one for post. I'm 100% sure it hits the post one

Comment: I tried to do E2E test via selenium, and I got the same issue. I removed the UI part and started to do only integration test

Comment: can you update the question with the code missing `...` from ResetPage.post?

Comment: The code works fine when I test it through a browser, however, doesn't work in a unittest.

Comment: maybe something weird about `get_payload`. where is it defined? can you print it's contents?

Comment: No, it works fine in the browser, the issue is with the unittest. Here is my get_payload http://codepad.org/6WFqbSaZ

Comment: Exactly, since it works from the browser probably the input you send from the test is different. Did you try printing `payload['password']` before calling save?

Comment: got the answer from someone on IRC channel.

Comment: my http requests are going through my dev server, and I should have a running test server instead.

Comment: awesome. yeah that makes total sense! django's `django.test.Client` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/. Django rest framework also has a similar one, that's the one we use for rest endpoints.. and use requests/selenium for e2e tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh from the database

self.user.refresh_from_db()

````
import urllib2
import requests
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.test import TestCase
from adaptors.redis_class import DjangoRedis


class PasswordChange(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='john', email='john@john.com', password='john') #Modified
        # class for redis access  
        r = DjangoRedis()
        r.set("email:john@john.com", '0' * 40, ex=3600)
        r.set('0' * 40, "email:john@john.com", ex=3600)
    def test_change_password(self):
        # Fake url I set through redis
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/' + '0' * 40 + '/'
        r = requests.get(url)
        csrf_token = r.content.split('csrf_token')[1].split('"')[2]
        payload = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token, 'payload': json.dumps({'password': 'johnjohn'})}
        headers = {'Cookie': 'csrftoken=' + csrf_token}
        data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        json_res = json.loads(response.read())

        # This doesn't fail
        self.assertEqual(json_res['password_changed'], True)
        self.user.refresh_from_db() #modified

        # This fails
        self.assertEqual(self.user.check_password('johnjohn'),True)```
````